# How to view H2 in-memory database while integration tests are running?

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, h2, spring-test

How do I view the H2 in-memory database while integration tests are running? The H2WebServer is started at the beginning of my integration tests. But the H2WebServer doesn't respond to my browser request when I have set a breakpoint in the code which makes it impossible to actually view the database..

Comment: I believe you can use a jdbc client (like squirrel) to connect directly to the DB

Answer (score 1):

If you add this to your spring config file for the test context, you should be able to connect to the database with a regular SQL client such as Squirrel.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>
               jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb;check_props=true;default_schema=true;
           </value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>sa</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value></value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Your solution works for running a Spring application with h2 in-memory. **But** how do you view the in-memory database **while** running integration tests?

Comment: what I do is run the tests in debug mode, add a breakpoint in my IDE and when the test stops at the breakpoint, I fire up SQL Developer and connect to the database to query it.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, once the code stops at a breakpoint during an integration tests, the internal H2 Server is also stopped.

Comment: Same problem. As soon as the program hits a breakpoint i cannot access the web console anymore. Is there a way around this?